# How do I capture the output of an email in Rails and put it in a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

The output from an email sent from ActionMailer output to the log, I wanted to know if I could get that output into a variable so I can store it in a file.

**Ps.** I forgot to mention that this is on Rails 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As McStretch has pointed out, observer is the best way to handle every message that is delivered by a mailer. However, if you'd like to just capture 1 or 2 special cases, you can do the following:

Assuming you have an ActionMailer subclass called `MyMailer`, and an email called `foobar`,

```
# Rails 2.x
mail = MyMailer.create_foobar(...) # instead of MyMailer.deliver_foobar(...)
File.open('filename.txt', 'wb') {|f| f.write(mail.body) }
MyMailer.deliver(mail)

# Rails 3.x
mail = MyMailer.foobar(...) # instead of MyMailer.foobar(...).deliver
File.open('filename.txt', 'wb') {|f| f.write(mail.body) }
mail.deliver
```

Comment: For some reason MyMailer.foobar is throwing an error "undefined method 'foobar' for MyMailer:Class" ... where names of functions and classes have been changed to protect the guilty. Odd thing is it was working at first.

Comment: Figured it out ... the Rails 2 version should be 'mail = MyMailer.create_foobar(...)' ...

Comment: If you need to capture HTML and text separately: mail.parts[0].body (text) mail.parts[1].body (HTML)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [register_interceptor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-c-register_interceptor) or [register_observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-c-register_observer) methods on ActionMailer to do something before or after sending the mail, respectively. The ActionMailer docs state:

> Action Mailer provides hooks into the
>   Mail observer and interceptor methods.
>   These allow you to register objects
>   that are called during the mail
>   delivery life cycle.
>
> An observer object must implement the
>   :delivered_email(message) method which
>   will be called once for every email
>   sent after the email has been sent.
>
> An interceptor object must implement
>   the :delivering_email(message) method
>   which will be called before the email
>   is sent, allowing you to make
>   modifications to the email before it
>   hits the delivery agents. Your object
>   should make and needed modifications
>   directly to the passed in
>   Mail::Message instance.

Each of these methods provide a Mail::Message as an argument, so you should be able to get the desired data from that object and save it somewhere:

```
class  MyInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(mail)
    # do something before sending the email
  end
end

class MyObserver
  def self.delivered_email(mail)
     # do something after sending the email
  end
end
```

- Example above from http://blog.envylabs.com/2010/04/new-in-rails3-beta2/

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is on Rails 2